# About Project.toml

Tags: julia

I would like to ask, before julia1.0, when configuring mybinder, I only need REQUIRE, format for example:

```
julia 0.6.0
PyCall
PyPlot
...
```

After updating to `julia 1.1.0`, this doesn't seem to work anymore. I saw that it might be necessary to replace `REQUIRE` with `project.toml`, but how should `project.toml` be generated if I only know the list of the packages names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add packages `Project.toml`

1. Go to the folder where your project is located, for example

   ```
   $ cd /home/myname/MyProject.jl
   ```
2. Start Julia

   ```
   $ julia
   ```
3. Press `]` to go to the package manager and type `activate`:

   ```
   (v1.0) pkg> activate .
   ```
4. Add the packages that you wish to add:

   ```
   (MyProject.jl) pkg> add Test
   ```
5. This will update the `Project.toml` file

#### Comments

1. If you do not have a `Project.toml` file to start with the recommended way is to generate one along a project folder using projecct manager the command: `(v1.0) pkg> generate MyProject.jl`
2. You still need to have the `REQUIRE` file to be present if you want to register official Julia packages (attobot needs them)